# Photoshop javascript traversing folder hierarchy UPWARDS

Tags: javascript, recursion, photoshop

First of all let me tell you that I only got basic programming experience, yet I am nearly a professional in MaxScript (Autodesk 3ds max scripting language). Now I'm starting to write a script for Photoshop which basically does the following:

1) Manipulate an open PSD document in a certain way

2) Save that document as TIFF at a specific folder relative to the PSD files' location.

So let's say the PSD File is in folder *c/project/postproduction/working/workingSubfolder*

The TIFF file should then be in the folder *c/project/postproduction/export/exportSubfolder*

The important things are:

- The folder "working" and "export" are on the same level
- There sometimes is not a "workingSubfolder" folder, sometimes there
  are more. Not predictable.
- The script needs to replicate the folder structure of the "working" folder inside the "export" folder but obviously saving TIFFs there instead of PSDs.

**What I need now is a way to traverse a hierarchy upwards from the PSD file until a folder named "export" gets found. Then go inside that "export" folder, replicate the structure inside the "working" folder there, if that structure doesn't exist yet and then save the TIF file with the same name as the PSD file there.**

I found a ton in the interwebs about traversing a folder tree recursively downwards, but nothing upwards. Maybe I'm searching wrong? I feel like this is a reeeaally simple problem to solve for any decent programmer.

Comment: Traversing _down_ usually requires reading data from the file system – but since you have an existing path already and want to go “up” here, in first place this requires basic string manipulation – split your path at the `/`, and go through the results of that split in reverse order, until you find your path segment named `export`. Only after that, you need to go “down” again – by that time you will know the names of the folders below already, so then it is a matter of checking whether those already exist in the file system, and if not creating them.

Comment: But this should not require recursion at any point, since you simply have a “flat”, one-dimensional data structure here – just a couple of path segments in defined order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you started... Essentially it is simply calculating what the output path should be from the current documents path with some strategic replacements. If you actually need to work with the file system objects more, see the 'Javascript Tools Guide' in your Photoshop install directory.

```
var workingPath  = app.activeDocument.path.toString();
var exportPath = workingPath.replace('working', 'export');
var filename = app.activeDocument.name.toString().replace('.psd', '.tif');
var folder = new Folder(exportPath);

if (!folder.exists)
    folder.create();

 var options = new TiffSaveOptions;
//set any options you need to here....

var exportFile = new File(exportPath + '/' + filename )

 app.activeDocument.saveAs(exportFile, options)
```

Comment: Oh my god, that's so simple. I really didnt get the thought that I could just replace "working" with "export" and it would solve all the hassle. Thanks so much for that :-)